# I cannot connect to my own IRC server with python socket

Tags: python, linux, sockets, irc, cjk

*I am Japanese and I am not good at speaking English. Please let me know if there is anything I say that you don't understand.*

I have a question regarding Python's socket module.

I am setting up an IRC server on a virtual machine and I am trying to create an IRC bot with Python, but I am unable to connect to the server.

I have tried the following minimal code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(5) # set timeout to 5 seconds
sock.connect(('xxx.xx.xxx.xx', 6667))
```

However, it times out and I am unable to connect. I have checked the server's IP address using ping and it returns a response. The virtual machine is running CentOS 7 and both SElinux and firewall are disabled. Ruby code works properly and LimeChat2 on my local PC can also connect without any issues.

Please let me know what could be the possible reasons for this issue. The port number is correct.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the code shown. *"Ruby code works properly"* - please show the ruby code for comparison. Also, does the ruby code work from the same (virtual) machine you are trying the Python code from? *"I have checked the server's IP address using ping and it returns a response."* - neither a successful nor an unsuccessful ping say anything about the reachability of a specific port on the target machine.

Comment: *"I am Japanese and I am not good at speaking English."* - in case this helps: there is a japanese stackoverflow site: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm sorry. When I woke up this morning and checked, I realized that the last digit of my IP address was incorrect.

Thank you for letting me know that there is a Japanese Q&A site for programming,